# Sprockets::FileNotFound (for gem ActiveAdmin)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

couldn't find file 'jquery.ui.datepicker'   (in C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/bundler/gems/active_admin-f65e7cd6425b/app/assets/javascripts/active_admin/base.js.coffee:2)

Think that problem with gem 'sprockets'

```
sprockets (2.11.0) lib/sprockets/context.rb:106:in `resolve'
sprockets (2.11.0) lib/sprockets/context.rb:146:in `require_asset'
sprockets (2.11.0) lib/sprockets/directive_processor.rb:217:in `process_require_directive'
sprockets (2.11.0) lib/sprockets/directive_processor.rb:167:in `block in process_directives'
sprockets (2.11.0) lib/sprockets/directive_processor.rb:165:in `each'
sprockets (2.11.0) lib/sprockets/directive_processor.rb:165:in `process_directives'
sprockets (2.11.0) lib/sprockets/directive_processor.rb:99:in `evaluate'
tilt (1.4.1) lib/tilt/template.rb:103:in `render'
sprockets (2.11.0) lib/sprockets/context.rb:197:in `block in evaluate'
sprockets (2.11.0) lib/sprockets/context.rb:194:in `each'
sprockets (2.11.0) lib/sprockets/context.rb:194:in `evaluate'
sprockets (2.11.0) lib/sprockets/processed_asset.rb:12:in `initialize'
sprockets (2.11.0) lib/sprockets/base.rb:374:in `new'
sprockets (2.11.0) lib/sprockets/base.rb:374:in `block in build_asset'
sprockets (2.11.0) lib/sprockets/base.rb:395:in `circular_call_protection'
sprockets (2.11.0) lib/sprockets/base.rb:373:in `build_asset'
sprockets (2.11.0) lib/sprockets/index.rb:94:in `block in build_asset'
sprockets (2.11.0) lib/sprockets/caching.rb:58:in `cache_asset'
sprockets (2.11.0) lib/sprockets/index.rb:93:in `build_asset'
sprockets (2.11.0) lib/sprockets/base.rb:287:in `find_asset'
sprockets (2.11.0) lib/sprockets/index.rb:61:in `find_asset'
sprockets (2.11.0) lib/sprockets/processed_asset.rb:111:in `block in resolve_dependencies'
sprockets (2.11.0) lib/sprockets/processed_asset.rb:105:in `each'
sprockets (2.11.0) lib/sprockets/processed_asset.rb:105:in `resolve_dependencies'
sprockets (2.11.0) lib/sprockets/processed_asset.rb:97:in `build_required_assets'
sprockets (2.11.0) lib/sprockets/processed_asset.rb:16:in `initialize'
sprockets (2.11.0) lib/sprockets/base.rb:374:in `new'
sprockets (2.11.0) lib/sprockets/base.rb:374:in `block in build_asset'
sprockets (2.11.0) lib/sprockets/base.rb:395:in `circular_call_protection'
sprockets (2.11.0) lib/sprockets/base.rb:373:in `build_asset'
sprockets (2.11.0) lib/sprockets/index.rb:94:in `block in build_asset'
sprockets (2.11.0) lib/sprockets/caching.rb:58:in `cache_asset'
sprockets (2.11.0) lib/sprockets/index.rb:93:in `build_asset'
sprockets (2.11.0) lib/sprockets/base.rb:287:in `find_asset'
sprockets (2.11.0) lib/sprockets/index.rb:61:in `find_asset'
sprockets (2.11.0) lib/sprockets/processed_asset.rb:111:in `block in resolve_dependencies'
sprockets (2.11.0) lib/sprockets/processed_asset.rb:105:in `each'
sprockets (2.11.0) lib/sprockets/processed_asset.rb:105:in `resolve_dependencies'
sprockets (2.11.0) lib/sprockets/processed_asset.rb:97:in `build_required_assets'
sprockets (2.11.0) lib/sprockets/processed_asset.rb:16:in `initialize'
sprockets (2.11.0) lib/sprockets/base.rb:374:in `new'
sprockets (2.11.0) lib/sprockets/base.rb:374:in `block in build_asset'
sprockets (2.11.0) lib/sprockets/base.rb:395:in `circular_call_protection'
sprockets (2.11.0) lib/sprockets/base.rb:373:in `build_asset'
sprockets (2.11.0) lib/sprockets/index.rb:94:in `block in build_asset'
sprockets (2.11.0) lib/sprockets/caching.rb:58:in `cache_asset'
sprockets (2.11.0) lib/sprockets/index.rb:93:in `build_asset'
sprockets (2.11.0) lib/sprockets/base.rb:287:in `find_asset'
sprockets (2.11.0) lib/sprockets/index.rb:61:in `find_asset'
sprockets (2.11.0) lib/sprockets/bundled_asset.rb:16:in `initialize'
sprockets (2.11.0) lib/sprockets/base.rb:377:in `new'
sprockets (2.11.0) lib/sprockets/base.rb:377:in `build_asset'
sprockets (2.11.0) lib/sprockets/index.rb:94:in `block in build_asset'
sprockets (2.11.0) lib/sprockets/caching.rb:58:in `cache_asset'
sprockets (2.11.0) lib/sprockets/index.rb:93:in `build_asset'
sprockets (2.11.0) lib/sprockets/base.rb:287:in `find_asset'
sprockets (2.11.0) lib/sprockets/index.rb:61:in `find_asset'
sprockets (2.11.0) lib/sprockets/environment.rb:75:in `find_asset'
sprockets (2.11.0) lib/sprockets/base.rb:295:in `[]'
sprockets-rails (2.0.1) lib/sprockets/rails/helper.rb:144:in `lookup_asset_for_path'
sprockets-rails (2.0.1) lib/sprockets/rails/helper.rb:91:in `block in javascript_include_tag'
sprockets-rails (2.0.1) lib/sprockets/rails/helper.rb:90:in `map'
sprockets-rails (2.0.1) lib/sprockets/rails/helper.rb:90:in `javascript_include_tag'
actionpack (4.0.4) lib/action_view/template.rb:143:in `block in render'
activesupport (4.0.4) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:161:in `instrument'
actionpack (4.0.4) lib/action_view/template.rb:141:in `render'
actionpack (4.0.4) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:61:in `render_with_layout'
actionpack (4.0.4) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:47:in `render_template'
actionpack (4.0.4) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:17:in `render'
actionpack (4.0.4) lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:42:in `render_template'
actionpack (4.0.4) lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:23:in `render'
actionpack (4.0.4) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:127:in `_render_template'
actionpack (4.0.4) lib/action_controller/metal/streaming.rb:219:in `_render_template'
actionpack (4.0.4) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:120:in `render_to_body'
actionpack (4.0.4) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:33:in `render_to_body'
actionpack (4.0.4) lib/action_controller/metal/renderers.rb:26:in `render_to_body'
actionpack (4.0.4) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:97:in `render'
actionpack (4.0.4) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:16:in `render'
actionpack (4.0.4) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:41:in `block (2 levels) in render'
activesupport (4.0.4) lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:12:in `block in ms'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/benchmark.rb:295:in `realtime'
activesupport (4.0.4) lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:12:in `ms'
actionpack (4.0.4) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:41:in `block in render'
actionpack (4.0.4) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:84:in `cleanup_view_runtime'
activerecord (4.0.4) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:25:in `cleanup_view_runtime'
actionpack (4.0.4) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:40:in `render'
actionpack (4.0.4) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:10:in `default_render'
actionpack (4.0.4) lib/action_controller/metal/responder.rb:233:in `default_render'
actionpack (4.0.4) lib/action_controller/metal/responder.rb:161:in `to_html'
actionpack (4.0.4) lib/action_controller/metal/responder.rb:154:in `respond'
actionpack (4.0.4) lib/action_controller/metal/responder.rb:147:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.4) lib/action_controller/metal/mime_responds.rb:330:in `respond_with'
devise (3.2.4) app/controllers/devise/sessions_controller.rb:10:in `new'
actionpack (4.0.4) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:4:in `send_action'
actionpack (4.0.4) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:189:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.0.4) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:10:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.0.4) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:18:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (4.0.4) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:443:in `_run__644442672__process_action__callbacks'
activesupport (4.0.4) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:80:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (4.0.4) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:17:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.0.4) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:29:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.0.4) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:31:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (4.0.4) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (4.0.4) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
activesupport (4.0.4) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `instrument'
actionpack (4.0.4) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.0.4) lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:250:in `process_action'
activerecord (4.0.4) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.0.4) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:136:in `process'
actionpack (4.0.4) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:44:in `process'
actionpack (4.0.4) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:195:in `dispatch'
actionpack (4.0.4) lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:13:in `dispatch'
actionpack (4.0.4) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:231:in `block in action'
actionpack (4.0.4) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:80:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.4) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:80:in `dispatch'
actionpack (4.0.4) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:48:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.4) lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:44:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.4) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:71:in `block in call'
actionpack (4.0.4) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:59:in `each'
actionpack (4.0.4) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:59:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.4) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:674:in `call'
warden (1.2.3) lib/warden/manager.rb:35:in `block in call'
warden (1.2.3) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `catch'
warden (1.2.3) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/etag.rb:23:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:25:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/head.rb:11:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:27:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:241:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:225:in `context'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:220:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:486:in `call'
activerecord (4.0.4) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:36:in `call'
activerecord (4.0.4) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:626:in `call'
activerecord (4.0.4) lib/active_record/migration.rb:373:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:29:in `block in call'
activesupport (4.0.4) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:373:in `_run__988967824__call__callbacks'
activesupport (4.0.4) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:80:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (4.0.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:64:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:76:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:17:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
railties (4.0.4) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
railties (4.0.4) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'
activesupport (4.0.4) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `block in tagged'
activesupport (4.0.4) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
activesupport (4.0.4) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `tagged'
railties (4.0.4) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
activesupport (4.0.4) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:83:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:64:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:112:in `call'
railties (4.0.4) lib/rails/engine.rb:511:in `call'
railties (4.0.4) lib/rails/application.rb:97:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:60:in `service'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/server.rb:191:in `block in start_thread'
```

waiting for your suggestion.
Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

the problem is that the latest version of jquery-ui used a hyphen ('jquery-ui/datepicker') instead of a point ('jquery.ui.datepicker'). You have to add jquery-ui-rails gem in your Gemfile, and must be the version '4.2.1',apparently this is currently used to sprockets

Add to your Gemfile

```
gem 'jquery-ui-rails', '~> 4.2.1'
```

Runs `bundle update`, and voila, all works fine